# chromedriver launches chromium but cant load the site

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

i am trying to do basic stuff with selenium. when google chrome is installed, the below code works and does everything thats required but the same setup doesnt work with chromium. it launches the chromium browser but doesnt load the site. i have checked that the version of chromium and chrome driver also are same. and i can only use chromium for my project. this is scala code.

code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./chromedriver")
val options = new ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*")
val driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
val link = "https://www.google.com/"
driver.get(link)
```

logs:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995}) on port 30314
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
{"message":"Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist \nHost info: host: 'zxcv-boomslang', ip: '127.0.1.1'\nBuild info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'\nSystem info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.19.0-38-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_202'\nDriver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver\nCommand: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}}]"}
```

tried searching everywhere but cant find a solution.

Comment: Add tag of your language

Comment: Change `chromedriver` to `chromedriver.exe`. See if this works.

Comment: its a linux environment and the file is without the .exe

Comment: What is your **language**, looks not Python

Comment: its scala/java.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following options also, these two stopped the error for me

```
val options = new ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")// overcome limited resource problems
```

If its still not working try adding

```
 options.addArguments("--headless")
```